# No administrative panel in alfresco

Tags: windows, authentication, alfresco

I integrated system credential with alfresco, but I am unable to see the admin tool or admin panel in alfresco explorer. I am not able to login to old admin login. I am able to login using domain login, but I dont have admin tool

Here is the code I added in global properties

```
### ACtive Directory Configuration ###
authentication.chain=passthru1:passthru,ldap1:ldap
passthru.authentication.sso.enabled=false
passthru.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
passthru.authentication.authenticateCIFS=false
passthru.authentication.authenticateFTP=false
passthru.authentication.servers=192.168.100.100
passthru.authentication.domain=<Netbios Domain>
passthru.authentication.useLocalServer=false
passthru.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=abc\sameer
passthru.authentication.connectTimeout=5000
passthru.authentication.offlineCheckInterval=300
passthru.authentication.protocolOrder=TCPIP,NETBIOS
ldap.authentication.active=false
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s
ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
ldap.authentication.java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://192.168.100.100:389
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInBind=false
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInUid=false
ldap.synchronization.active=true
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=<Netbios Domain>\\  <administrator.privilege.account>
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=<administrator.privilege.account.password>
ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize=1000
ldap.synchronization.groupDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass=nogroup)(!(modifyTimestamp<\={0})))
ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(&(objectclass=user)(userAccountControl\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803\:\=512))
ldap.synchronization.personDifferentialQuery=(& (objectclass=user)(!(modifyTimestamp<\={0})))
ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(objectclass\=group)
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=cn\=users,dc=<company.domain>,dc=com
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=cn\=users,dc=<company.domain>,dc=com
ldap.synchronization.modifyTimestampAttributeName=modifyTimestamp
ldap.synchronization.timestampFormat=yyyyMMddHHmmss'.0Z'
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=sAMAccountName
ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sn
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName=msExchALObjectVersion
ldap.synchronization.defaultHomeFolderProvider=userHomesHomeFolderProvider
ldap.synchronization.groupIdAttributeName=cn
ldap.synchronization.groupType=Nogroup
ldap.synchronization.personType=user
ldap.synchronization.groupMemberAttributeName=member
synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=true
cifs.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add alfrescoNtlm back to your authentication-chain to be able to use your admin account again:

```
authentication.chain=passthru1:passthru,ldap1:ldap,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm
```

afterwards check if your user's where successfully imported from your LDAP, if not check & test your settings with a LDAP browser:

You'll also have to adjust this, as you specified sAMAccountName is userID:

```
passthru.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=sameer
```

Furthermore, please be aware that you have to provide your ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal as principal name format like:

```
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=uid\=sameer,cn\=users,dc=<company.domain>,dc=com
```

Comment: thanks now I am able to login but how to add userspace to these windows login. I am not able to able to create new content using windows login

Comment: that should be threated in other question

Comment: Using this login credential I have to login two times. First I have to login in browser then in alfresco login page. How to make make it as single login page

Comment: set ldap.authentication.active=true to enable your ldap-auth. If there is a browser login popup then you've somehow enabled an SSO subsystem

Comment: no it is not working still I have to login two times. But my global property is set as  

`passthru.authentication.sso.enabled=false`